# tsc: is there any way to specify no watch on the command line?

Tags: typescript

In the Typescript compiler cli, is there any way to specify no watch on the command line, i.e. to override the config from `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: well.. can't you remove it from tsconfig and use tsc -w when you need to watch?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> i.e. to override the config from tsconfig.json

No. you really should not have `watch` in tsconfig.json and specify it only when you need it on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

There is no CLI way that I know of. In order to achieve that write a nodejs script which overrides watch to be false. Run the tsc with execSync and change the file back. Here is the nutshell untested.

```
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync

var pathTofile = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'tsconfig.json');
var config  = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(pathTofile, 'utf8'));
config.watch = false;
fs.writeFileSync(pathTofile, JSON.stringify(config),{encoding:'utf8'});
execSync('tsc');
config.watch = true;
fs.writeFileSync(pathTofile, JSON.stringify(config),{encoding:'utf8'});
```